# How to preserve new line in shell script output?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a line in my shell script like below

```
output_logs=`sh script2.sh $1 $2`
```

`script2.sh` produce lots of lines of logs. I want to `grep` specific lines of its output. The problem I have is `$output_logs` has the entire output of `script2.sh` as a single line string and `grep` produces strange results because of this. How to get the logs from `script2.sh` to be stored in individual lines?

Comment: You aren't showing how you know what `$output_logs` does or doesn't contain -- if you're running `echo $output_logs` and thinking this reflects the variable's output accurately, well, there's your problem (aka [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)).

Comment: I did exactly the same. I did echo `$output_logs`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try something like this.

```
output_logs=`sh script2.sh $1 $2`
echo "$output_logs"
```

Note that this is different from `echo $output_logs`.

The double-quoted version of the variable preserves internal spacing of the value exactly as it is represented in the variable — newlines, tabs, multiple blanks and all — whereas the unquoted version replaces each sequence of one or more blanks, tabs and newlines with a single space.

Comment: `"$1" "$2"`, if we don't want string-splitting there too. (I wonder if the OP *really* wants to pass all parameters, ie. `"$@"`).